# Force file encoding in Microsoft Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

I am dynamically creating CSV files using php, and I have a problem with the encoding when I open it with Microsoft Excel. The problem is with the french characters `'` , `é` , `à` ...

When I changed my Excel's encoding to UTF-8 it works just fine. But I don't want to make a manual for each user who downloads the file.

Is there a way to force Excel to open the file with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Why not just convert the csv to UTF-8?

Comment: Just add the BOM to the beginning of the file, as in one of the dupe answers.